# Update fb-like-box onclick with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook

I want to update the facebook like box from the form input. After a check button is clicked. The new like box will appear in the div.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="facebook Page URL" 
id="fbURL" value="cnn">             

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="fbChk">check</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#fbPage').append('<div id="fb-like" class="fb-like-box" 
data-href="http://www.facebook.com/RTnews" 
data-width="500" data-show-faces="true" 
data-stream="false" data-header="true"></div>');

    $("#fbChk").click(function() {
        var fbURL = $("#fbURL").val(); 
        $('#fbPage').html('<div id="fb-like" class="fb-like-box" 
         data-href="http://www.facebook.com/'+fbURL+'" 
         data-width="500" data-show-faces="true" 
         data-stream="false" data-header="true"></div>');
      });
```

When I run this script. Old facebox disappear without a new on show.

Comment: try pasting the `browser console` output, that will help diagnose the problem!

Answer (score 0):

This could easily be done with a frontend framework like react or so, but in jQuery I see  two choices, when you click on the button `$.hide()` the first div and `$.append()` the second div or you can dispaly the second div and give the prop `display: none` .  When you click the button, you can show the second div with `$.show()` and hide the first one..or try to use `innerHTML()` instead  of `$.html()`.

Comment: Please show me the code. I'm not good at jquery much.

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle or a live demo to edit it for you?

Comment: JSFIddle doesn't show up the facebook like box. Don't know why.